# How to map list of list items to index in HorizontalPager?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

I have a List

```
val listOfList: List<SublistObject> = emptyList()
```

, which in turn consists again of sub lists:

```
@Serializable
data class SublistObject(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val pages: List<HorizontalScrollerPage> = emptyList()
)
```

The pages in SublistObject might have different size. E.g. we have a list of `SublistObject`, where as the first `SublistObject` has 3 pages. The second `SublistObject` has 2 pages. And the third `SublistObject` has 3 pages :

1. SublistObject : * * *
2. SublistObject : * *
3. SublistObject : * * *

So we would have 3 lists with 8 items in total. I would like to traverse them like:

1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 3.1 -> 3.2 -> 3.3

what I do like:

```
listOfLists.forEach{ subList ->
    subList.forEach{ item ->
        print(item)
    }
}
```

But I would like to show each element in an

```
HorizontalPager(count = totalPagesCount){ index ->
   val item = listOfLists.get(index)
}
```

1. How can I calculate the amount of all items easily (without two `forEach`s)?
2. How can I map e.g. index 4 to 2.2 ? Or how to use `flatMap` or `flatMapIndexed()` here?

Comment: 1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2.1 -> 2.2 -> 3.1 -> 3.2 -> 3.3
 do you mean list to list / list to item ?
pls provide an example because its ambiguous

Comment: @Mohmmaed-Amleh I updated the data structure above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple. Here it would return list of pages where it will take all pages from each items and does the transformation.

```
var flattenedMap = listOfLists.flatMap{it.pages}
```

I have just replicated your scenario with simple code. Hope it will work for you.

```
data class SublistObject(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val pages: List<HorizontalScrollerPage> = emptyList()
){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Id:$id -- ${pages.joinToString(",")}\n"
    }
}

class HorizontalScrollerPage(var pageNo: Int = Random.nextInt(100)){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "PageNo: $pageNo"
    }
}


    val listOfList: ArrayList<SublistObject> = arrayListOf()
    listOfList.add(
        SublistObject(
            id = 1,
            pages = arrayListOf(HorizontalScrollerPage(), HorizontalScrollerPage(), HorizontalScrollerPage())
        )
    )
    listOfList.add(
        SublistObject(
            id = 2,
            pages = arrayListOf(HorizontalScrollerPage(), HorizontalScrollerPage(), HorizontalScrollerPage())
        )
    )
    println("---Separate List: ---")
    println(listOfList.joinToString(""))
    println("---Flattened List: ---")
val flattenedList :List<HorizontalScrollerPage> = listOfList.flatMap { it.pages }
println(flattenedList)
```

[image]

Comment: The first line solved it all: var flattenedMap = listOfLists.flatMap{it.pages}
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate list for this:

```kotlin
val flatList = listOfLists.flatten()
```

And then all elements will be there as you expect, and you can query the `.size` and ask for a specific index with `flatList[index]`.

Comment: where is flatten() coming from?

Comment: It's in the standard library https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flatten.html